# Condicional en template string

Tags: javascript, template-strings

tengo un archivo json con 50 productos de los cuales cada producto tiene un array con fotos, el caso es que algunos tienen 1 foto y otros 2.
Quiero armar un map con una template string para pintar esas fotos en el dom. si mapeo el indice 0 del array todo va bien porque todos tienen fotos, pero el indice 1 solo unos pocos tienen fotos y salta error, como puedo poner un condicional en el map o en la template string para evaluar si no tiene foto? (para probar cambiar  por  en dejo el ejemplo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    img{
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="lista"></div>

  <script>
    let $contenido = [],
    $lista = document.querySelector(".lista");

    getData();

    async function getData(){
      try{
        let res = await fetch("/Productos-V2.json"),
          json = await res.json();

        if(!res.ok) throw{ status: res.status, statusText: res.statusText }
        
        $contenido = json.map(el => `<img src="${el.Fotos[0].Foto}">`);
        console.log($contenido)
        document.querySelector(".lista").insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", $contenido.join(""));


      }catch(err){
        let message = err.statusText || " Ocurrió un error";
        $lista.innerHTML = `Error ${err.status}:${message}`;
      }finally{ }
    }
  </script>
  
</body>

</html>
```

aqui esta el json

```
[
    {
    "ProductoID": 12,
    "Modelo": "HB01-150",
    "Descripcion": "Luminaria High Bay (UFO) Antideslumbramiento",
    "UnidadesEmbalaje": 1,
    "Especificaciones": [
      {
        "Descripcion": "Potencia",
        "Valor": "150",
        "Unidad": "W"
      },
      {
        "Descripcion": "Dimmable",
        "Valor": "NO"
      },
      {
        "Descripcion": "Tensión",
        "Valor": "100~277",
        "Unidad": "VCA"
      },
      {
        "Descripcion": "Eficiencia",
        "Valor": "130",
        "Unidad": "Lm/W"
      },
      {
        "Descripcion": "Cantidad de leds",
        "Valor": "288"
      },
      {
        "Descripcion": "Protección",
        "Valor": "IP66"
      },
      {
        "Descripcion": "Factor de Potencia",
        "Valor": ">0,95"
      },
      {
        "Descripcion": "Ángulo de Haz",
        "Valor": "60",
        "Unidad": "º"
      },
      {
        "Descripcion": "C.R.I.",
        "Valor": ">70"
      }
    ],
    "Fotos": [
      {
        "Foto": "https://electrobroker.com/admin/fotos/201915150715 - Cengo-ZHN.png"
      },
      {
        "Foto": "https://electrobroker.com/admin/fotos/201922150722 - Cengo-ZHN-100-150-200-240.png"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "ProductoID": 13,
    "Modelo": "HB01-200",
    "Descripcion": "Luminaria High Bay (UFO) Antideslumbramiento",
    "UnidadesEmbalaje": 1,
    "Especificaciones": [
      {
        "Descripcion": "Potencia",
        "Valor": "200",
        "Unidad": "W"
      },
      {
        "Descripcion": "Dimmable",
        "Valor": "NO"
      },
      {
        "Descripcion": "Tensión",
        "Valor": "100~277",
        "Unidad": "VCA"
      },
      {
        "Descripcion": "Eficiencia",
        "Valor": "125",
        "Unidad": "Lm/W"
      },
      {
        "Descripcion": "Cantidad de leds",
        "Valor": "288"
      },
      {
        "Descripcion": "Protección",
        "Valor": "IP66"
      },
      {
        "Descripcion": "Factor de Potencia",
        "Valor": ">0,95"
      },
      {
        "Descripcion": "Ángulo de Haz",
        "Valor": "60",
        "Unidad": "º"
      },
      {
        "Descripcion": "C.R.I.",
        "Valor": ">70"
      }
    ],
    "Fotos": [
      {
        "Foto": "https://electrobroker.com/admin/fotos/201915150715 - Cengo-ZHN.png"
      },
      {
        "Foto": "https://electrobroker.com/admin/fotos/201922150722 - Cengo-ZHN-100-150-200-240.png"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "ProductoID": 14,
    "Modelo": "HB01-240",
    "Descripcion": "Luminaria High Bay (UFO) Antideslumbramiento",
    "UnidadesEmbalaje": 1,
    "Especificaciones": [
      {
        "Descripcion": "Potencia",
        "Valor": "240",
        "Unidad": "W"
      },
      {
        "Descripcion": "Dimmable",
        "Valor": "NO"
      },
      {
        "Descripcion": "Tensión",
        "Valor": "100~277",
        "Unidad": "VCA"
      },
      {
        "Descripcion": "Eficiencia",
        "Valor": "120",
        "Unidad": "Lm/W"
      },
      {
        "Descripcion": "Cantidad de leds",
        "Valor": "288"
      },
      {
        "Descripcion": "Protección",
        "Valor": "IP66"
      },
      {
        "Descripcion": "Factor de Potencia",
        "Valor": ">0,95"
      },
      {
        "Descripcion": "Ángulo de Haz",
        "Valor": "60",
        "Unidad": "º"
      },
      {
        "Descripcion": "C.R.I.",
        "Valor": ">70"
      }
    ],
    "Fotos": [
      {
        "Foto": "https://electrobroker.com/admin/fotos/201915150715 - Cengo-ZHN.png"
      },
      {
        "Foto": "https://electrobroker.com/admin/fotos/201922150722 - Cengo-ZHN-100-150-200-240.png"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "ProductoID": 15,
    "Modelo": "HB01-100-D",
    "Descripcion": "Luminaria High Bay (UFO) Antideslumbramiento - Dimmerizable",
    "UnidadesEmbalaje": 1,
    "Especificaciones": [
      {
        "Descripcion": "Potencia",
        "Valor": "100",
        "Unidad": "W"
      },
      {
        "Descripcion": "Dimmable",
        "Valor": "SI"
      },
      {
        "Descripcion": "Tensión",
        "Valor": "100~277",
        "Unidad": "VCA"
      },
      {
        "Descripcion": "Eficiencia",
        "Valor": "135",
        "Unidad": "Lm/W"
      },
      {
        "Descripcion": "Cantidad de leds",
        "Valor": "288"
      },
      {
        "Descripcion": "Protección",
        "Valor": "IP66"
      },
      {
        "Descripcion": "Factor de Potencia",
        "Valor": ">0,95"
      },
      {
        "Descripcion": "Ángulo de Haz",
        "Valor": "60",
        "Unidad": "º"
      },
      {
        "Descripcion": "C.R.I.",
        "Valor": ">70"
      }
    ],
    "Fotos": [
      {
        "Foto": "https://electrobroker.com/admin/fotos/201915150715 - Cengo-ZHN.png"
      },
      {
        "Foto": "https://electrobroker.com/admin/fotos/201922150722 - Cengo-ZHN-100-150-200-240.png"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "ProductoID": 16,
    "Modelo": "HB01-150-D",
    "Descripcion": "Luminaria High Bay (UFO) Antideslumbramiento - Dimmerizable",
    "UnidadesEmbalaje": 1,
    "Especificaciones": [
      {
        "Descripcion": "Potencia",
        "Valor": "150",
        "Unidad": "W"
      },
      {
        "Descripcion": "Dimmable",
        "Valor": "SI"
      },
      {
        "Descripcion": "Tensión",
        "Valor": "100~277",
        "Unidad": "VCA"
      },
      {
        "Descripcion": "Eficiencia",
        "Valor": "130",
        "Unidad": "Lm/W"
      },
      {
        "Descripcion": "Cantidad de leds",
        "Valor": "288"
      },
      {
        "Descripcion": "Protección",
        "Valor": "IP66"
      },
      {
        "Descripcion": "Factor de Potencia",
        "Valor": ">0,95"
      },
      {
        "Descripcion": "Ángulo de Haz",
        "Valor": "60",
        "Unidad": "º"
      },
      {
        "Descripcion": "C.R.I.",
        "Valor": ">70"
      }
    ],
    "Fotos": [
      {
        "Foto": "https://electrobroker.com/admin/fotos/201915150715 - Cengo-ZHN.png"
      },
      {
        "Foto": "https://electrobroker.com/admin/fotos/201922150722 - Cengo-ZHN-100-150-200-240.png"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "ProductoID": 17,
    "Modelo": "HB01-200-D",
    "Descripcion": "Luminaria High Bay (UFO) Antideslumbramiento - Dimmerizable",
    "UnidadesEmbalaje": 1,
    "Especificaciones": [
      {
        "Descripcion": "Potencia",
        "Valor": "200",
        "Unidad": "W"
      },
      {
        "Descripcion": "Dimmable",
        "Valor": "SI"
      },
      {
        "Descripcion": "Tensión",
        "Valor": "100~277",
        "Unidad": "VCA"
      },
      {
        "Descripcion": "Eficiencia",
        "Valor": "125",
        "Unidad": "Lm/W"
      },
      {
        "Descripcion": "Cantidad de leds",
        "Valor": "288"
      },
      {
        "Descripcion": "Protección",
        "Valor": "IP66"
      },
      {
        "Descripcion": "Factor de Potencia",
        "Valor": ">0,95"
      },
      {
        "Descripcion": "Ángulo de Haz",
        "Valor": "60",
        "Unidad": "º"
      },
      {
        "Descripcion": "C.R.I.",
        "Valor": ">70"
      }
    ],
    "Fotos": [
      {
        "Foto": "https://electrobroker.com/admin/fotos/201915150715 - Cengo-ZHN.png"
      },
      {
        "Foto": "https://electrobroker.com/admin/fotos/201922150722 - Cengo-ZHN-100-150-200-240.png"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "ProductoID": 18,
    "Modelo": "HB01-240-D",
    "Descripcion": "Luminaria High Bay (UFO) Antideslumbramiento - Dimmerizable",
    "UnidadesEmbalaje": 1,
    "Especificaciones": [
      {
        "Descripcion": "Potencia",
        "Valor": "240",
        "Unidad": "W"
      },
      {
        "Descripcion": "Dimmable",
        "Valor": "SI"
      },
      {
        "Descripcion": "Tensión",
        "Valor": "100~277",
        "Unidad": "VCA"
      },
      {
        "Descripcion": "Eficiencia",
        "Valor": "120",
        "Unidad": "Lm/W"
      },
      {
        "Descripcion": "Cantidad de leds",
        "Valor": "288"
      },
      {
        "Descripcion": "Protección",
        "Valor": "IP66"
      },
      {
        "Descripcion": "Factor de Potencia",
        "Valor": ">0,95"
      },
      {
        "Descripcion": "Ángulo de Haz",
        "Valor": "60",
        "Unidad": "º"
      },
      {
        "Descripcion": "C.R.I.",
        "Valor": ">70"
      }
    ],
    "Fotos": [
      {
        "Foto": "https://electrobroker.com/admin/fotos/201915150715 - Cengo-ZHN.png"
      },
      {
        "Foto": "https://electrobroker.com/admin/fotos/201922150722 - Cengo-ZHN-100-150-200-240.png"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "ProductoID": 19,
    "Modelo": "NK-UFO-12-E",
    "Descripcion": "Lámpara UFO 12W",
    "UnidadesEmbalaje": 20,
    "Especificaciones": [
      {
        "Descripcion": "Potencia",
        "Valor": "12",
        "Unidad": "W"
      },
      {
        "Descripcion": "Ángulo de Haz",
        "Valor": "170",
        "Unidad": "º"
      },
      {
        "Descripcion": "Input voltage",
        "Valor": "175-250",
        "Unidad": "V"
      },
      {
        "Descripcion": "Frecuencia",
        "Valor": "50",
        "Unidad": "Hz"
      },
      {
        "Descripcion": "C.R.I.",
        "Valor": ">80"
      },
      {
        "Descripcion": "Diámetro",
        "Valor": "125",
        "Unidad": "mm"
      },
      {
        "Descripcion": "Altura",
        "Valor": "75",
        "Unidad": "mm"
      },
      {
        "Descripcion": "Luminous Flux",
        "Valor": "1020",
        "Unidad": "lm (±10%)"
      },
      {
        "Descripcion": "Zócalo",
        "Valor": "E27"
      }
    ],
    "Fotos": [
      {
        "Foto": "https://electrobroker.com/admin/fotos/201934140434 - Enshine-UFO.png"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "ProductoID": 22,
    "Modelo": "NK-UFO-18-E",
    "Descripcion": "Lámpara UFO 18W",
    "UnidadesEmbalaje": 10,
    "Especificaciones": [
      {
        "Descripcion": "Potencia",
        "Valor": "18",
        "Unidad": "W"
      },
      {
        "Descripcion": "Ángulo de Haz",
        "Valor": "170",
        "Unidad": "º"
      },
      {
        "Descripcion": "Input voltage",
        "Valor": "175-250",
        "Unidad": "V"
      },
      {
        "Descripcion": "Frecuencia",
        "Valor": "50",
        "Unidad": "Hz"
      },
      {
        "Descripcion": "C.R.I.",
        "Valor": ">80"
      },
      {
        "Descripcion": "Diámetro",
        "Valor": "125",
        "Unidad": "mm"
      },
      {
        "Descripcion": "Altura",
        "Valor": "81",
        "Unidad": "mm"
      },
      {
        "Descripcion": "Luminous Flux",
        "Valor": "1275",
        "Unidad": "lm (±10%)"
      },
      {
        "Descripcion": "Zócalo",
        "Valor": "E27"
      }
    ],
    "Fotos": [
      {
        "Foto": "https://electrobroker.com/admin/fotos/201934140434 - Enshine-UFO.png"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "ProductoID": 23,
    "Modelo": "NK-UFO-24-E",
    "Descripcion": "Lámpara UFO 24W",
    "UnidadesEmbalaje": 10,
    "Especificaciones": [
      {
        "Descripcion": "Potencia",
        "Valor": "24",
        "Unidad": "W"
      },
      {
        "Descripcion": "Ángulo de Haz",
        "Valor": "170",
        "Unidad": "º"
      },
      {
        "Descripcion": "Input voltage",
        "Valor": "175-250",
        "Unidad": "V"
      },
      {
        "Descripcion": "Frecuencia",
        "Valor": "50",
        "Unidad": "Hz"
      },
      {
        "Descripcion": "C.R.I.",
        "Valor": ">80"
      },
      {
        "Descripcion": "Diámetro",
        "Valor": "200",
        "Unidad": "mm"
      },
      {
        "Descripcion": "Altura",
        "Valor": "95",
        "Unidad": "mm"
      },
      {
        "Descripcion": "Luminous Flux",
        "Valor": "2040",
        "Unidad": "lm (±10%)"
      },
      {
        "Descripcion": "Zócalo",
        "Valor": "E27"
      }
    ],
    "Fotos": [
      {
        "Foto": "https://electrobroker.com/admin/fotos/201934140434 - Enshine-UFO.png"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ya casi lo tienes, lo que debes hacer es volver a usar [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) sobre el campo `Fotos` de cada elemento de tu `Array`:

```js
let $contenido = json.map(el => {         // <- aquí aplicas map sobre cada elemento de json
  return el['Fotos'].map(foto => {        // <- aquí aplicas map sobre cada elemento de Fotos
    return `<img src="${foto['Foto']}">`  // <- aquí devuelves el template
  }).join("");                            // <- aquí usas join para evitar la separación con coma (separación por defecto si no se usa otro carácter)
});
```

Usando la estructura mostrada en tu pregunta, podemos ver el siguiente `snippet`:

```js
// variable de muestra:
let json = [
  {
    "Fotos": [
      {
        "Foto": "https://electrobroker.com/admin/fotos/201915150715 - Cengo-ZHN.png"
      },
      {
        "Foto": "https://electrobroker.com/admin/fotos/201922150722 - Cengo-ZHN-100-150-200-240.png"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Fotos": [
      {
        "Foto": "https://electrobroker.com/admin/fotos/201934140434 - Enshine-UFO.png"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Fotos": [
      {
        "Foto": "https://electrobroker.com/admin/fotos/201934140434 - Enshine-UFO.png"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Fotos": [
      {
        "Foto": "https://electrobroker.com/admin/fotos/201915150715 - Cengo-ZHN.png"
      },
      {
        "Foto": "https://electrobroker.com/admin/fotos/201922150722 - Cengo-ZHN-100-150-200-240.png"
      }
    ]
  }
];

// el método aplicado sobre la variable de muestra
let $contenido = json.map(el => {
  return el['Fotos'].map(foto => {
    return `<img src="${foto['Foto']}">`
  }).join("");
});
document.querySelector(".lista").insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", $contenido.join(""));
```

```css
img{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="lista" class="lista"></div>
```

Espero que esto aclare tu duda y te ayude a resolver el problema.

**EDICIÓN**

De acuerdo a tus oportunos comentarios, lo que deseas es mostrar las imágenes de la posición 1 (recordemos que el tipo `Array` se indexa a partir de cero en [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)). Si el `Array` no tiene imagen en la posición 1, entonces no se debe mostrar nada.

Para solucionar esto puedes usar un [operador condicional ternario](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) o usar el método [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

**Condicional ternario**

Podemos devolver el valor del elemento en la posición 1 del `Array` de "Fotos" si el mismo existe o devolver una cadena vacía en caso contrario, para ello debemos *preguntar* si el elemento existe.

Javascript, a diferencia de otros lenguajes, no bota una excepción de índice fuera de rango cuando se intenta acceder a un índice que no está definido en un `Array`, sino que devuelve `undefined`. Podemos usar esto en nuestro favor, ya que `undefined` es un valor [`falsy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy), que al ser evaluado en un entorno booleano, devolverá `false`.

Gracias a este comportamiento podemos escribir un operador condicional ternario, preguntando por el valor del elemento en la posición `i` de un `Array`. Si el elemento es distinto de `undefined` (en realidad si es distinto de cualquier valor `falsy`) significa que el elemento contiene la `url` de la imagen (de acuerdo a lo que se recibe en la respuesta).

Así, podríamos tener la siguiente lógica:

```js
let $contenido = json.map(el => {             // <- aquí aplicas map sobre cada elemento de json
  return `${el.Fotos[1] ? `<img src="${el.Fotos[1].Foto}">` : ''}`; // <- operador condicional ternario
});
```

Así, estamos devolviendo el valor esperado si acaso existe un elemento en la posición 1 del `Array` de "Fotos" o una cadena vacía en caso contrario.

```js
// variable de muestra:
let json = [
  {
    "Fotos": [
      {
        "Foto": "https://electrobroker.com/admin/fotos/201915150715 - Cengo-ZHN.png"
      },
      {
        "Foto": "https://electrobroker.com/admin/fotos/201922150722 - Cengo-ZHN-100-150-200-240.png"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Fotos": [
      {
        "Foto": "https://electrobroker.com/admin/fotos/201934140434 - Enshine-UFO.png"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Fotos": [
      {
        "Foto": "https://electrobroker.com/admin/fotos/201934140434 - Enshine-UFO.png"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Fotos": [
      {
        "Foto": "https://electrobroker.com/admin/fotos/201915150715 - Cengo-ZHN.png"
      },
      {
        "Foto": "https://electrobroker.com/admin/fotos/201922150722 - Cengo-ZHN-100-150-200-240.png"
      }
    ]
  }
];

// el método aplicado sobre la variable de muestra
let $contenido = json.map(el => {             // <- aquí aplicas map sobre cada elemento de json
  return `${el.Fotos[1] ? `<img src="${el.Fotos[1].Foto}">` : ''}`; // <- operador condicional ternario
});
document.querySelector(".lista").insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", $contenido.join(""));
```

```css
img{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="lista" class="lista"></div>
```

**Usando `filter()`**

También puedes usar `filter`, para aplicar un filtro sobre los elementos de tu `Array` de "Fotos" y quedarte sólo con los elementos que tengan más de una foto. Eso te garantiza que podrás acceder sin problemas a la posición 1.

```js
// filtramos por el tamaño del `Array` Fotos
let filtrado = json.filter(el => {
  return el.Fotos.length > 1;
});
// ahora podemos acceder con seguridad al elemento en el índice 1
let $contenido = filtrado.map(el => {
  return `<img src="${el.Fotos[1].Foto}">`;  // <- accedemos sin problemas al elemento en la posición 1
});
```

Podemos ver este resultado en el siguiente `snippet`:

```js
// variable de muestra:
let json = [
  {
    "Fotos": [
      {
        "Foto": "https://electrobroker.com/admin/fotos/201915150715 - Cengo-ZHN.png"
      },
      {
        "Foto": "https://electrobroker.com/admin/fotos/201922150722 - Cengo-ZHN-100-150-200-240.png"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Fotos": [
      {
        "Foto": "https://electrobroker.com/admin/fotos/201934140434 - Enshine-UFO.png"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Fotos": [
      {
        "Foto": "https://electrobroker.com/admin/fotos/201934140434 - Enshine-UFO.png"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Fotos": [
      {
        "Foto": "https://electrobroker.com/admin/fotos/201915150715 - Cengo-ZHN.png"
      },
      {
        "Foto": "https://electrobroker.com/admin/fotos/201922150722 - Cengo-ZHN-100-150-200-240.png"
      }
    ]
  }
];

// filtramos por el tamaño del `Array` Fotos
let filtrado = json.filter(el => {
  return el.Fotos.length > 1;
});
// ahora podemos acceder con seguridad al elemento en el índice 1
let $contenido = filtrado.map(el => {
  return `<img src="${el.Fotos[1].Foto}">`;
});
document.querySelector(".lista").insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", $contenido.join(""));
```

```css
img{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="lista" class="lista"></div>
```

Comment: No estoy ahora con la compu para probarlo pero creo que con tu solucion traeria todas las fotos del array Fotos, yo lo que quiero es iterar sobre Fotos[0] o Fotos[1] segun necesidad, sobre [0] no hay problema porque todos tienen un objeto Fotos pero sobre [1] algunos lo tienen y otros no y ahi salta el undefined. Lo que se me ocurrio mentalmente (no pude probarlo aun en la practica) es poner un condicional que evalue si Fotos[1].Fotos es undefined, en ese caso aplicar un return. estimo puede funcionar. Gracias por tu tiempo @Mauricio Contreras

Comment: El método `map` itera sobre todos los elementos del `array` llamado "Fotos", tanto tenga este 1 o más fotos. El problema se podría presentar cuando no existan fotos en el `Array`, pero entiendo que esa situación no sucedería. Saludos

Comment: pero como haria para tomar solo las fotos de la posicion [1] del array? es aqui donde como no todas tienen salta error

Comment: Pues no te entiendo, ¿deseas mostrar sólo las imágenes de la posición 1? ¿Eso significa que no mostrarás las imágenes de la posición 0 en aquellos elementos que tengan más de 1 imágen? ¿A la vez mostrar las imágenes de los que tengan sólo 1 imagen?

Comment: las dos cosas, por un lado mostrar los de la posicion 0, o sea todos tienen imagen y por otro lado los de la posicion 1, solo algunos tienen imagen. Entiendo que el problema esta en que el array fotos en algunos tiene posicion 0 y 1 y en otros solo 0 por lo tanto cuando intento iterar sobre la posicion 1 en los que solo tienen 0 da un undefined, el tema seria poder manejar un condicional donde si el array fotos tiene length de 1 no lo tome en cuenta (ese seria el que solo tiene 1 foto)

Comment: es que no me doy cuenta como meter el if dentro del callback del map

Comment: Es que mi solución hace eso que planteas, no necesitas un `if`. Revisa el resultado y te darás cuenta. Saludos

Comment: lo acabo de probar y tu solucion trae tanto las fotos de la posicion 0 como las de la 1, yo quiero traer solo la posicion 1 en aquellos que si la tengan. Por eso sale error, porque hay algunos que no tienen posicion 1

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122819/discussion-between-mauricio-contreras-and-hernan-garcia).

Comment: Aunque las 2 opciones son valederas la que buscaba era la del operador ternario, yo casi la tenia pero no sabia que poner ante la condicion else, nunca hubiera imaginado que era una cadena vacia. El escollo mas grande que encontre hasta ahora en mis 5 meses que llevo con html/css/javascript (y con 51 años de edad, jaja), gracias a esta comunidad que cuenta con gente como tu que desinteresadamente te tomaste el trabajo de ayudarme con la solucion, muchisimas Gracias!!!